# Find date stored in MySQL row, find all entries after that date in one query

Tags: mysql, rate-limiting

I have a table that stores actions for rate-limiting purposes. What I want to do is fetch the newest row that has a 'key_action' (the action that starts the time for rate-limiting) and then find all entries after that date.

The only way I can currently think to do it is with two queries:

1. `SELECT created_at FROM actions WHERE key_action=1 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1`
2. `SELECT * FROM actions WHERE created_at >= (created_at from query 1)`

Is there a was to combine these two queries into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make query 1 a subquery of query 2.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM actions 
    WHERE created_at >= (SELECT MAX(created_at) 
                             FROM actions 
                             WHERE key_action=1)
```

Comment: i was under the impression LIMIT was not allowed in subqueries in MySQL http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/211237

Comment: @DTest: Modified my answer with an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have thought @Joe Stefanelli's answer was right, but Limits are not allowed in subqueries in WHERE statement. From [this workaround](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/211239), I put together this query (not tested)

```
SELECT * FROM actions 
JOIN (SELECT created_at FROM actions WHERE key_action=1 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1) createdActions
WHERE actions.created_at >= createdActions.created_at
```